# Add a close button to the Divi Theme dropdown menu

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Does anyone know where I'd go to add an X to close a Divi menu? Im making a full screen menu and there isnt a close button. 
I believe this is the html I'd edit but not sure where it is found

```
<span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use JavaScript for this type of thing, if you're aiming to close the menu. Here's an example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

The "×" within the "a" selectors is what makes the X symbol.
**closeNav Function:**

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

The id "main" is the main content of the page, while the "sideNav" ID could be your menu bar ID. This was a piece of code that I used to close a sidebar navigation menu, but I think you can make it fit to your uses.

Comment: Do you know / work in WordPress? This answer doesn't put this into WordPress context, so would be very difficult indeed to implement.  In WordPress, jQuery is ubiquitous, so it may also make more sense to roll a jQuery answer. Furthermore, it's actually _not true_ you need javascript to render an open / close menu interface. Example: https://codepen.io/arthurtw/pen/Vjpmwq